# stopping excel saving E20 as exponent

Tags: excel

I have a string 300E20 which represents a company code.  When I put this into Excel and save the spreadsheet it becomes an exponent.
I can stop this by preformatting the column as Text.
However, I am receiving this as a csv or xlsx file from someone who is not proficient in Excel.  Is there any way to reverse the scientific notation?

Comment: It will probably be difficult after the fact because when you see 3E+22 in the cell after opening a CSV, Excel has already lost the information about whether it was originally 300E20, 30E21 or 3000E19. Can you ensure that it is enclosed in quotes in the CSV?  e.g. `"300E20"`?

Comment: This https://superuser.com/questions/1083454/editing-csv-file-in-excel-always-converts-number-column-to-scientific-notation might be able to help-- it suggests using  Text Import Wizard instead of just "opening" the CSV, or this https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text/307498#307498 which has a VBA routine to open the CSV as "all text". Or do you actually have "3E+22" in the CSV itself?

Comment: I have csv in the file itself.  I think your point about enclosing in quotes is good.  Otherwise, tell them to put it into Notepad instead of Excel.